# Reactive Method call in meteor is not Reactive

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

we use ReactiveMethod calls inside helpers in meteor.But most of the time without refreshing the browser it show the previous data(if the passed parameters are not changed). What is the solution for this?

inside helpers I use below method

```
customerOutsTanding: function(){ 
return ReactiveMethod.call("outstanding",customerId); 
}
```

outstanding will pay using boostrap model input text and it will close.But using reactive method calling it will not update.after refreshing the browser it will get update

Comment: Can't help you much without you showing any implementation code.

Comment: inside helpers I use below method

customerOutsTanding: function(){

   return ReactiveMethod.call("outstanding",customerId);

}

outstanding will pay using boostrap model input text and it will close.But using reactive method calling it will not update.after refreshing the browser it will get update

Answer (score 0):

`ReactiveMethod.call` is only called again when the parameters changes. In your case parameter is`customerId` which is not getting changed since its not a reactive data source.

You probably need to use `Tracker.Dependency` (https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#tracker_dependency) to reactively trigger this function again. Something like this

```
var outstandingDep = new Tracker.Dependency;

customerOutsTanding: function(){ 
  outstandingDep.depend();
  return ReactiveMethod.call("outstanding",customerId); 
}
```

Then when you want to change the dependency which is not clear from the question you need to call `outstandingDep.changed()` may be you need to call when the input text changes.